# Migration from SQL Server 2008 to Postgres 9.2

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I have a rather large database (2 GB of data, 25 million rows in the largest table) on a shared web hosting. The database engine is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Due to high fees for the SQL Server web hosting, I would like to migrate my data from SQL Server to a Postgres database.

In my SQL Server database I have tables, indexes, constraints and stored procedures. The data types in my tables are `VARCHAR`, `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT`, `SMALLDATETIME`, `REAL` and `FLOAT`.

In my stored procedures I am using some built-in T-SQL Date/Time manipulation functions like `DateAdd()` or `DatePart()`.

Is there any FREE tool available that would help me migrate my data (tables, constraints, and if possible also the stored procedures) from SQL Server to Postgres?

Comment: There is a new project for this: https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql but I don't know how good this is.

Comment: Pg PL/SQL is quite different from T-SQL, so it may be overall cheaper to rewrite functions. Good luck with your migration!

Comment: Have a look at tPostgres, which essentially runs T-SQL against PostgreSql. http://www.openscg.com/2014/01/tpostgres-features-sybase-sql-server-compatibility/

Comment: How many tables are there? If it is just a few, you could use an ETL tool like Pentaho. But it does not move data structures/code.

Comment: There's 25 tables in my DB. 10 of them are 'big' tables with my time-series data and the remaining ones are small metadata tables. I'll probably try  [sqlserver2postgresql](http://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql) to recreate the database schema and then take a look at Pentaho ETL tool to move the data.

Answer (score 0):

TinyInt and SmallDateTime (AFAIK) are non-SQL Standard datatypes.
EDIT: SQL Standard types nearest equivalents are, respectively, SMALLINT and TIMESTAMP. I suggest you do an conversion of columns using those types **before** the migration to see if you identify any issues with the application. It's your call to solve that before the migration or note that in a checklist for use after. The nearest MSSQL equivalent of TIMESTAMP (AFAIK) is DATETIME2.

I believe that most of the tables creation script is capable of running with few edits.
Additional index creation can be more trouble if you used some unique capabilities 
of SQL Server. An decent DB case tool can make that transition less difficult (sorry, don't know of a free one - we use ER/Studio here for MSSQL).

Stored Procedures - that's where is the real pain. You have to learn the PL/pgSQL and translate your logic to it. Since tricks used on one db engine have very high chance of 
not working/getting very lousy performance on another, get an Postgres database developer to help you on that.
EDIT: While an DB case tool can do a decent job converting an db structure from an engine to another, I firmly believe that an tool to convert stored procedures from an procedure language to another can cause more harm than progress.

Comment: There is no `DATETIME2` in Postgres (and in ANSI SQL). The ANSI types are `date`, `time` and `timestamp`

Comment: Yes, it seems I'll have to use timestamp or 'timestamp with time zone' instead of SmallDateTime.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I though that modification as a step BEFORE the OP start making the PGSQL database - still in MSSQL2008

Answer (score 0):

I had written a process back in 2005 to use bcp to dump the data out then pg_import the data and do all the schema scripting and conversion necessary. Procs are slightly different because of syntax discrepancies.